# Поисковый движок для сайта

Tags: php, mysql, sphinx

Я хочу организовать поиск по сайту, сайт многоязычный, есть два варианта для поиска: `elasticsearch` или `sphinx`. Второй вариант мне показался проще в понимании и установке. Как я понял из примеров на разных сайтах на `sphinx` можно создать индексацию только одной таблицы. Но мне нужно чтоб поиск велся не только по одной таблице, например статьи, есть еще поиск по пользователям, вакансиям, и прочее. Плюс ко всему поиск должен работать как на кириллице так и на латинице. Вопрос конкретен: как эти пункты решить с помощью `sphinx`?

Comment: *как эти пункты решить с помощью sphinx?* Изучить документацию на продукт. Официальную, а не "примеры на разных сайтах" - они могут быть лишь дополнением.

Comment: Если коротко, то строите индекс по каждой таблице, при этом язык можно вынести параметром в индекс, чтобы можно было по нему фильтровать. При поступлении поисковой строки от пользователя делает поиск по требуемым индексам. Так что все пункты решаемы

Comment: Используйте sphinxql - с ним вы можете легко создавать сколько угодно индексов на сколько угодно таблиц